# Random number generation with user-defined Mean and StdDev

Tags: vba, excel, random

I am attempting to generate normally distributed random variables.
I have a user input for the total number of variables (M), the number of sets of random variables (N). I am using the formula `=NORM.INV(RAND(),0,1)` and it works fine.
However when I want to have a user input Mean and StdDev, I declare a variable for each. The cell that is bring referenced by the variable I put say a 0 for Mean and 1 for StdDev.
The code will run, however the output of the random variables is the good old `#NAME?`.

I do not understand why referencing a cell if just entering the formula on the worksheet works, but in VBA it does not?

The code is:

```
Sub RandomNorm()

Dim WS_W As Worksheet: Set WS_W = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Working") ' Sheet for calculations
Dim WS_Rand As Worksheet: Set WS_Rand = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Random Generated") ' Sheet for random variable generation

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim N As Long: N = WS_W.Range("B3").Value ' Number of random variable sets
Dim M As Long: M = WS_W.Range("C3").Value ' Number of simulations

WS_W.Select

Dim Mean As Double: Mean = WS_W.Cells(3, 4).Value ' Mean of Normal distribution
Dim StdDev As Double: StdDev = WS_W.Cells(3, 5).Value ' Standard Deviation of normal distribution

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

WS_Rand.Select
WS_Rand.Cells.Select
Selection.ClearContents ' Prepare for generation by clearing Generation sheet

For i = 1 To N
    For j = 1 To M
        WS_Rand.Cells(j, i).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=NORM.INV(RAND(),Mean,StdDev)"
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: AHHH. You are spot on.

Comment: ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=NORM.INV(RAND()," & Mean & "," & StdDev & ")"

Comment: Thanks mate. Mark this as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Excel worksheet formula calculation engine does not know anything about your VBA variables.

You are assigning a formula to cells and attempting to use variables from VBA in the formula. Since Excel does not recognize the literal text of each variable name this results in a #NAME? error.

The fix is to replace the variable names with their values:

```
ActiveCell = "=NORM.INV(RAND()," & Mean & "," & StdDev & ")"
```

As a side note... you can assign the formula to the entire range of cells in one go rather than looping the assignment cell by cell, and nothing needs to be selected in order to assign the formula.